# Salvando ID de uma tabela com duas Primary Keys com Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, chave-estrangeira, chave-primária

Olá, eu estou tendo um problema ao salvar dados em uma última tabela.
Bom, essa tabela tem duas foreign keys e as mesmas são primary keys:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao ir no Controller, salvar a tabela, eu uso os códigos a seguir:

```
 itv.setId();
    itv.setIngresso(ing);
    itv.setVenda(ven);
    itv.setItvqtde(Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("txtqtde")));

    itvDao.salvarItemVenda(itv);
    response.sendRedirect("my-tickents-buy.jsp");
```

Aqui está o meu ItemVendaDao:

```
 public void salvarItemVenda(ItemVenda itv){


    try {

    s = new ConnectionFactory().getSessionFactory();
    tx = s.beginTransaction();
    s.save(itv);
    tx.commit();
    s.close();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item venda salva com sucesso");


    } catch (Exception e) {

        tx.rollback();

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao salvar item venda" +e.getMessage());
      s.close();


    }


}
```

O que é preciso colocar no itv.setId()? 
Quando mapeio ele cria esse método para salvar o Id do item venda, sendo que o ID do item venda são dois: o objeto do ingresso e o objeto da venda, ambos já estão sendo salvos acima com o código:

```
 itv.setIngresso(ing);
    itv.setVenda(ven);
```

Novamente, o que é preciso colocar no **itv.setId()**?

Aqui está o ItemVenda.java (mapeado automaticamente pelo hibernate)

```
public class ItemVenda  implements java.io.Serializable {


 private ItemVendaId id;
 private Ingresso ingresso;
 private Venda venda;
 private int itvqtde;

public ItemVenda() {
}

public ItemVenda(ItemVendaId id, Ingresso ingresso, Venda venda, int itvqtde) {
   this.id = id;
   this.ingresso = ingresso;
   this.venda = venda;
   this.itvqtde = itvqtde;
}

public ItemVendaId getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(ItemVendaId id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public Ingresso getIngresso() {
    return this.ingresso;
}

public void setIngresso(Ingresso ingresso) {
    this.ingresso = ingresso;
}
public Venda getVenda() {
    return this.venda;
}

public void setVenda(Venda venda) {
    this.venda = venda;
}
public int getItvqtde() {
    return this.itvqtde;
}

public void setItvqtde(int itvqtde) {
    this.itvqtde = itvqtde;
}
```

E o ItemVendaId.java está da seguinte forma:

```
public class ItemVendaId  implements java.io.Serializable {


 private int itvvencodigo;
 private int itvingressocodigo;

public ItemVendaId() {
}

public ItemVendaId(int itvvencodigo, int itvingressocodigo) {
   this.itvvencodigo = itvvencodigo;
   this.itvingressocodigo = itvingressocodigo;
}

public int getItvvencodigo() {
    return this.itvvencodigo;
}

public void setItvvencodigo(int itvvencodigo) {
    this.itvvencodigo = itvvencodigo;
}
public int getItvingressocodigo() {
    return this.itvingressocodigo;
}

public void setItvingressocodigo(int itvingressocodigo) {
    this.itvingressocodigo = itvingressocodigo;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inicialmente, vou recomendar você ter uma chave primária para cada tabela. essa chave primária seria seria um campo de ID.

Se precisar que suas chaves estrangeiras sejam únicas na tabela use o atributo UNIQUE.

Vou recomendar você usar anotações JPA nas suas tabelas para auxiliar o Hibernate (se já estiver usando xml recomendo mudar para Anotações):

```
@Entity
public class ItemVenda  implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ingresso_id")
    private Ingresso ingresso;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "venda_id")
    private Venda venda;

    private int qtde;

    //getters e setters omitidos
}
```

Você teria também as classes Venda e Ingresso com seus respectivos campos.
E teria apenas estas três tabelas. A tabela ItemVenda ficaria com os campos:
id, ingresso_id, venda_id, qtde

Sempre deixando o Hibernate tomar conta disso para você.

Neste caso o seu método setId() da classe ItemVenda só seria utilizado em casos de update.

Comment: Então você me recomendaria a criar uma ID na tabela do item venda? Ficaria assim:

create table itemvenda(

itvcodigo integer not null auto_increment primary key,

);

Comment: Exatamente e esse seria o código para criação manual. Ainda assim, recomendo que você configure o Hibernate para criar/atualizar automaticamente as tabelas para você (considerando que ainda esteja em fase de desenvolvimento e não existem dados importantes no banco).

Answer (score 1):

Se o conjunto de duas ou mais colunas que, combinadas, nunca se repetirão, você não precisa (e nem deve) criar uma coluna extra somente para servir como chave primária (como @Shura16 sugeriu). Você só estará criando uma coluna totalmente desnecessária visando somente a sua facilidade no desenvolvimento e fugindo da performance e boa integridade de dados no banco de dados.

No seu caso, você precisa criar uma chave composta. Simples assim.
Na JPA existem duas formas de fazer isso. Uma é através de IdClass e a outra, que eu recomendo, é através de EmbeddedId e Embeddable.

Digamos que você tem uma Classe A, uma Classe B e, uma terceira, Classe C onde a sua chave primária é composta da união de Classe A e B.

Ficaria assim:

**Classe A:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLASSE_A")
public class ClasseA {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CLASSE_A_ID")
    private Long id;

}
```

**Classe B:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLASSE_B")
public class ClasseB {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CLASSE_B_ID")
    private String id;

}
```

Antes de criar a classe C, você deverá criar uma classe que irá incorporar a Classe A e Classe B. Esta classe que irá representar a sua chave composta.

**Classe C PK:**

```
@Embeddable
public class ClasseCPK {

    @Column(name = "CLASSE_A_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long classeAId;

    @Column(name = "CLASSE_B_ID", nullable = false)
    private String classeBId;

}
```

Observe a anotação @Embeddable em ClasseCPK. Isto serve para informar ao JPA que esta classe servirá como uma chave composta.
Repare também que os seus atributos são somente uma referência ao tipo dos atributos de Classe A e B. Ou seja, Long e String.

Finalmente a nossa Classe C ficará assim:

**Classe C:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLASSE_C")
public class ClasseC {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ClasseCPK pk = new ClasseCPK();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CLASSE_A_ID", referencedColumnName = "CLASSE_A_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private ClasseA classeA;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CLASSE_B_ID", referencedColumnName = "CLASSE_B_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private ClasseB classeB;

}
```

E isto termina o mapeamento.

Mais um detalhe. Só mande o Hibernate criar as tabelas/colunas para você se o seu projeto for pequeno/amador. Se for um projeto grande e importante, como para uma instituição financeira e afins, nunca deixe o Hibernate interferir na estrutura do banco de dados, pois este mesmo banco de dados poderá (e muito provavelmente será) ser utilizado em outros sistemas e de diferentes linguagens.

Bônus: Caso uma entidade sua referencie uma outra que possui chave composta, você deverá usar a anotação @JoinColumns.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Respondendo diretamente a sua pergunta **"..o que é preciso colocar no itv.setId()?"**

Conforme o seu código esse ID é formado por um objeto `ItemVendaId`, então basta instanciá-lo no momento de gravar que tudo deve funcionar.

Como você não mostrou o código das classes Ingresso e Venda, estou chutando o nomes dos ID's deles. Segue exemplo:

```
itv.setId(new ItemVendaId(ven.getitvvencodigo(), ing.getitvingressocodigo()));
itv.setIngresso(ing);
itv.setVenda(ven);
itv.setItvqtde(Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("txtqtde")));
itvDao.salvarItemVenda(itv);
response.sendRedirect("my-tickents-buy.jsp");
```

Em todo caso, assim como os outros colegas que responderam antes, não recomendo esse tipo de mapeamento.